# sqlalchemy first() and one() not returning first result

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to retrieve the first result from the following query:

```
category = db.query(Category).filter_by(category_name=category_name).first()
    
print(category)
```

The first time I click to run the query, it returns:
Category(category_id=2,category_name=food)

The second time I click to run the query, it returns:
Category(category_id=3,category_name= food )

It keeps fetching the next matching result, until there are no more matches and it returns None.

Is this the default behaviour of first() and is there a way I can consistently get the first result no matter how many times I click? I tried using one() and whilst that helped it also returns error if there are no matching records.

I am trying to prevent the user from entering duplicate Category names and this is allowing the user to enter duplicate values after clicking a few times as the query is not returning the first match....

Comment: If there is more than one row that satisfies the query, you need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure that the result is consistent, for example `db.query(Category).filter_by(category_name=category_name)order_by(Category.id).first()`.  If no order is specified the RDBMS may return any row that satisfies the query.

Comment: I just tried but order_by the results doesn't work as first() is still moving through the results in the same sequence....